# Traveling on honeymoon to Seattle from San Antonio - Am I too fat for seat?

Tags: air-travel, airlines

I am getting married this year.  My fiancé and I want to spend our honeymoon in Seattle. However I am extremely stressed out that I will not fit. I weigh about 315 pounds and am 5'5".  I am not an experienced flyer so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Which airline is plus-size friendly?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE and congratulations on the pending nuptials. The question linked by ptityeti answers for economy class, but [policies vary widely by airline](https://www.cheapair.com/blog/travel-tips/airline-policies-for-overweight-passengers-traveling-this-summer/), and you have not indicated which you will be taking. The physical configuration of specific aircraft can be found on [SeatGuru](http://www.seatguru.com/).

Comment: "What airline is plus size friendly?" I doubt any economy class experience could qualify as plus size friendly.  There is probably variation, but I suspect that the range is somewhere between "extremely unfriendly" and "don't even think about it."  I'm not very wide, but I'm tall, and these days, there's hardly an airplane in which I can find anything approaching comfort.  If I were any wider than I am, I would be universally miserable.

Comment: Check SouthWest, you can there buy a second seat to accommodate for your extended space needs, and if the flight is not sold out, _you get the money back_ (but if it _is_ sold out, you paid a second seat). I think this is a pretty fair and good offer.